# Meaning of the verb "land" in context

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

I have come across in the seventh episode of the seventh season of *Friends*. Here is the context:

> Joey: Yeah—Hey, don’t worry, she’s a terrific girl. And hey listen,
>   could you do me a favor? When she comes out could you just mention
>   that I’m not looking for a serious relationship; that’d be great.
>
> Rachel: Why?! What?! Are you kidding?!
>
> Joey: Just casually slip it in, y’know lay the groundwork. Tell her
>   uh, I’m a loner—No! An outlaw! Tell her she doesn’t want to get mixed
>   up with the likes of me.
>
> Rachel: Y’know what? That’s a lot to remember, can’t I just tell her
>   you’re a pig?
>
> Joey: Hey, I’m gonna call her later! Honest! Oh come on, Chandler used
>   to do it! He’d even make the girl pancakes! Plus, he’d make extras and
>   leave ‘em for me.
>
> Rachel: Well forget it, I’m not telling that girl anything. That is
>   not my responsibility.
>
> Joey: Fine! (Pause) Now, where’d we **land** on those pancakes? (She
>   chases him out the door as his date emerges from the bathroom.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [*land*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/land):

> *intransitive verb*
>   **2 b** : to come to be in a condition or situation
>          // **landed** in jail

In other words:

> "Now, where did we **end up** [with] those pancakes?"

Or, to paraphrase further:

> "Now, what decision did we make about those pancakes?"

In other words, Joey's hungry and he'd like it if Rachel made him some pancakes.